# Сохранить картинку android кэш

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, bitmap

Доброго времени суток. Есть вопрос, как сохранить имеющийся Bitmap в кэш телефона, после чего иметь легкий доступ к этому файлу, в рамках одного приложения.

Скачиваю картинку таким способом:

```
 @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            URL urlConnection = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

После чего использую в своих целях. Но как бы её сохранить и использовать в дальнейшем, не имея доступа к сети?

Answer (score 1):

После загрузки сохраните его в файл:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
//Задаете путь и имя
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "myBitmap.jpg")
file.createNewFile();
//Запись
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
fileOutputStream.write(bytes.toByteArray());
fileOutputStream.close();
```

Не забудьте завернуть в `try-catch` и необходимые разрешения на запись: `"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"`

Затем читаете из файла и загоняете в `Bitmap`:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapData , 0, bitmapData.length);
```